# Error not lodged in PHP POST

Tags: php

This is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
   {    
    if (empty($_POST["course"]))
       {$courseErr = "* Course is required";}
    else
    {
       $course = test_input($_POST["course"]);
    }

   if (empty($_POST["school"]))
      {$schoolErr = "* School is required";}
   else
    {$school = test_input($_POST["school"]);}
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
  <select id="courses" name="course" class="form-control input-xlarge">
    <option disabled = "disabled" value = ''> Select course </option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="controls">
  <select id="schools" name="school" class="form-control input-xlarge">
    <option disabled = "disabled" value = ''> Select school </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now this `option` boxes are populated from database based on users' previous selection and that works fine.

PROBLEM:
  If I try to echo out the errors without selecting anything from the options, it only echos out `$courseErr` and nothing is returned from `$schoolErr`.

```
if(($schoolErr = '') && ($courseErr = ''))
  {
     //execute codes
  }
else {
     echo '<h1>'.$schoolErr.'</h1>'; echo '<br/>';
     echo '<h1>'.$courseErr.'</h1>'; 
     }
```

Comment: You must use `==` or `===` to test values.

Comment: Arrghhh! Poor me! That's it! Thanks, immeasurably...

Answer (score 2):

`=` is used for assign value, in if condition use `==` or `===`

```
if(($schoolErr == '') && ($courseErr == ''))
  {
     //execute codes
  }
else {
     echo '<h1>'.$schoolErr.'</h1>'; echo '<br/>';
     echo '<h1>'.$courseErr.'</h1>'; 
}
```